# Как зациклить часть кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть бот-автокликер, нужно его зациклить и каждый цикл добавлять в  "keyboard.write('002')" значение +1, а когда дойдет до 2000, нужно остановить.
код:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.moveTo(975, 361)
pyautogui.leftClick()
keyboard.write('001')
time.sleep(0.3)
pyautogui.moveTo(1037, 756)
```

Comment: Может просто добавить цикл while?

Comment: А через for нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

i=0
while True:
    i+=1
    if i > 2000:
        break

    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.moveTo(975, 361)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    keyboard.write('001')
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1037, 756)
```

Comment: Ну можно и проcто `++i`. Да и вообще, не пойму, ну можно и тайм-функцию сделать со слипом, которая будет перезапускать саму себя до определенного момента, когда будет `2000`, будет выход из функции и все на этом.

Comment: Условие > 2000, не не катит?

Comment: @And Если человек не знает как делать циклы то наверное ему рано с более продвинутыми функциями знакомится мне кажется.

Comment: while i < 2000:

Comment: Катит, то, катит, но, что если счетчик будет передан другой итерации, вот тут-то и начнутся проблемы. Отнимания единицы, туда-сюда, так-как, у вас на этапе `i > 2000` будет `2001`, нежели просто сделать обычное сравнение и прибавления `++i` в конце цикла, а то и просто сделать `while i < 2000`, прям в условии.

Comment: @And Ну у вас же есть право на правки.

Comment: Но почему бы это не сделать вам и улучшить качество своего же ответа.

Comment: Не работает, выдает ошибку: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Krater Уверены что у вас там нет лишних символов в коде? Которые я почистил, типа апострофов ' одинарных кавычек и т.д. У меня лично все работает.